# Diplaying bitmap in custom view with scale type center inside

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, custom-view

I have customview for displaying two bitmaps but the problem is  it is scaling to center crop but I don't want to crop bitmap instead I want to display full bitmap in canvas.

```
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
 {      

    mLayoutWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    mLayoutHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    this.setMeasuredDimension(mLayoutWidth, mLayoutHeight);
    mBitmap = scaleCenterCrop(mBitmap, mLayoutWidth, mLayoutHeight);
    overlayDefault = FastBlur.doBlur(mBitmap, 20, false);
    overlayDefault = scaleCenterCrop(overlayDefault, mLayoutWidth,
            mLayoutHeight);
    overlay = mBitmap.copy(Config.ARGB_8888, true);
    overlay = scaleCenterCrop(overlay, mLayoutWidth, mLayoutHeight);
    cx = (mLayoutWidth - mBitmap.getWidth()) >> 1; 
    cy = (mLayoutHeight - mBitmap.getHeight()) >> 1;

    c2 = new Canvas(overlay);
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    final Rect bitmapRect = ImageViewUtil.getBitmapRectCenterInside(
            mBitmap.getWidth(), mBitmap.getHeight(), mLayoutWidth, mLayoutHeight);
    setBitmapRect(bitmapRect);

    invalidate();

}

public Bitmap scaleCenterCrop(Bitmap original, int deviceHeight,
        int deviceWidth) {
    int old_width = original.getWidth();
    int old_height = original.getHeight();

    float scale = Math.max((float) deviceHeight / old_height,
            (float) deviceWidth / old_width);
    float newWidth = scale * old_width;
    float newHeight = scale * old_height;
    float left = (deviceWidth - newWidth) / 2;
    float top = (deviceHeight - newHeight) / 2;
    RectF rectF = new RectF(left, top, left + newWidth, top + newHeight);
    Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createBitmap(deviceWidth, deviceHeight,
            original.getConfig());
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(scaled);
    canvas.drawBitmap(original, null, rectF, null);
    return scaled;
}
```

Comment: you dont need to create a scaled Bitmap, just scale your Canvas (Canvas.scale()/Canvas.translate()) or use Canvas.drawBitmap() with a Matrix parameter

Comment: I have tried with canvas scale option but it is not working as per my need can you give example for set matrix parameter

Comment: Matrix.setRectToRect()

Comment: @user3572506 have you found any solution?i have the same requirment